# Add legends to a Treemap with ggplot only when space inside blocks is too small

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with ggplot and treemapify to generate a treemap.

The problem is that some blocks are too small so i can't put text inside of them. I've been trying to use `scale_fill_manual` in order to generate some legends outside the graph by `breaks` argument but it comes with two problems. If I only specify the labels that I want, the other ones turn green and I can't change their fill collor. On the other hand, when I use all the labels it shows them all.

How can I choose which legends I want to show in the graph?

This is the resulting treemap when I try to add the legends with all labels

[image: img1]

This is the resulting treemap when I try to add the legends with the labels that I want

[image: img2]

This is the code I'm currently working on:

```
ggplot(TM_df, aes(label = Labels, area = Values, fill = Labels)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(fontface = "bold", colour = "white", place = "centre") +
  scale_fill_manual("", breaks = TM_df$Labels,
                    values = colores, drop = F) +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )
```

And this is my dataset:

```
TM_df <- data.frame( Labels = c("Servicios Personales\n10,643 mdp (-5.1%)", 
"Materiales y Suministros\n1,597 mdp (+16.1%)", "Servicios Generales\n2,346 mdp (-25.0%)", 
"Transferencias, Asignaciones,\nSubsidios y Otras Ayudas\n44,212 mdp (+8.8%)", 
"Bienes Muebles, Inmuebles e Intangibles\n112 mdp (-55.8%)", 
"Inversion Publica\n1,336 mdp (-29.3%)", 
"Inversiones Financieras\ny Otras Provisiones\n48 mdp (-35.2%)", 
"Deuda Publica\n8,977 mdp (+25.7%)"), 
Values = c(10643.28124, 1596.93410, 2346.43756, 44211.92169, 112.46303, 
1335.76290, 48.30434, 12080.91506, 8976.59709))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to prevent the fill colors to be removed when setting the breaks would be to make use of a named vector which assigns colors to category names:

```r
library(treemapify)
library(ggplot2)

colores <- scales::brewer_pal(palette = "Dark2")(8)
ggplot(TM_df, aes(label = Labels, area = Values, fill = Labels)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(fontface = "bold", colour = "white", place = "centre") +
  scale_fill_manual("",
    breaks = TM_df$Labels[c(5, 7)],
    values = setNames(colores, TM_df$Labels)
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )
```

[image]